# Why AR objects are trembling on vuforia`s 5*-markers?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

We build the app for the jewelry store where AR object (the ring) is recognized when the ios app camera is pointed on the paper (and metal) marker we built in Vuforia. This is 5* marker (which is considered to be a good quality according to Vuforia) that we place on the finger.

So what we have - we have a pretty fast recognition, BUT we have unpleasant shaking of the ring, that is being recognized. The closer we point the camera to the marker - the more shaking is seen.

The paper maker has a normal cylinder form. The lighting is always enough while testing, etc

Any ideas on why this shaking appears?

Thanks in advance!

We were trying different markers, test in different conditions with different lighting, we played with camera settings, used different vuforia versions, etc - no luck

Comment: Did you find a solution? Have you considered Extended tracking? How did you deploy your app? iOS, Android, native, unity?

Answer (score 1):

If you the target is cylindric in shape than you should create a Vuforia cylinder target https://library.vuforia.com/objects/cylinder-targets. Standard ImageTarget are expected to be planar in 3D shape. The detector  still works as as the plane can locally approximate the cylindrical geometry but tracking will be extremely inaccurate and brittle.